# My Angular 7 app is telling me 'The selector ... did not match any elements'

Tags: angular, components, angular7

I'm using Angular 7.  I have created a custom component, with the definition defined at src/app/organization/organization.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-organization',
  templateUrl: './organization.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./organization.component.css']
})
export class OrganizationComponent implements OnInit {

  private organizationForm:FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.organizationForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [''],
    });
  }

}
```

My src/app/app.module.ts looks like this

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { OrganizationComponent } from './organization/organization.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    OrganizationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    ReactiveFormsModule 
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [OrganizationComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My src/index.html file looks like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Orgfrontend</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-organization></app-organization>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, when I start up my app I get this JS error

```
Error: The selector "app-organization" did not match any elements
    at DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/esm5/platform-browser.js:2857)
    at DebugRenderer2.selectRootElement (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:15530)
    at createElement (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:10807)
    at createViewNodes (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:13961)
    at createRootView (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:13889)
    at callWithDebugContext (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:15314)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:14597)
    at ComponentFactory_.create (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:11494)
    at
```

I'm missing somethign real simple but I can't tell what it is.  Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:** Below is my src/index.html file after suggested answers ...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Orgfrontend</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check your `main.ts` and post the code over here

Answer (score 0):

Put `<app-organization></app-organization>` in your app.component html

Answer (score 0):

You should not edit the `index.html`. **bootstrap component** must be included at least. Name of selector is `<app-root>` by default. You can find out that in `app.module.ts`

Try the follow:

**index.html**

```html
<app-root></app-root>
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<app-organization></app-organization>
```

Comment: I edited my src/index.html file to only have <app-root> (updated my question) ,but I still get that error.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know why people say it’s not recommended to use any component in index.html but you can definitely add it it there only if you declare it in the entryComponents array in app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

1) create organization.component.ts and a organization.module.ts

2)Now your organization.module.ts is your parent module.

```
 bootstrap: [OrganizationComponent]
   export class organizationalModule{}
```

## 3) main.ts

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(organizationalModule)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

## 4) Now in index.html

```
<body>()
 <app-organization></app-organization>  <=== Here, root selector(now app- 
                                       <===== organization) resides
  </body>
```

## or,

## index.html

```
<body><app-root></app-root></body>
```

## app.component.html

`<app-organization></app-organization>`  <=== Inside (app-root, which is parent)

Comment: Hi, You reference "organization.module.ts" in step 2, but that wasn't one of the files generated when I ran "ng g component organization".  The files were "organization.component.spec.ts", "organization.component.ts," "organization.component.html," and "organization.component.css".

Comment: Create module.  ng g module organization

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a custom Angular Elements component in Angular 9+, I have removed this error by doing the following:

1. In your app.module.ts file remove the default "bootstrap" array
2. create an ngDoBootstrap method in your app.module.ts file.  My app.module.ts file looks like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CustomFormComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
  }

  ngDoBootstrap() {
    const el = createCustomElement(CustomFormComponent, { injector: this.injector });
    customElements.define('custom-form', el);
  }
}
```

It took me a bit of trial and error so hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: Thx, that was exactly what I was looking for!